# Write number as unicode to file

Tags: c#

I'm trying to write unicode string to file (in C#) but can't get it working.

If I do this the writing works:

```
string output = "य";
File.WriteAllText(destFilePath, output, Encoding.UTF8);
```

But the problem is that if I try to write a number to file it wont come as unicode:

```
int testNumber = 10000;
output += testNumber.ToString();
File.WriteAllText(destFilePath, output, Encoding.UTF8);
```

This will actually write 10000 to the file which is not what I want. I want the 10000 to become a single unicode character.

is this possible?

thx!

Comment: Find the Unicode char for "1000" (does it exists?) and write that char

Comment: Which Unicode character for 10.000 are you refering to: Roman ↂ, CJK 万/萬, or some other? And how should the program know which of these or others to use if you don't tell it?

Answer (score 3):

```
var testNumber = (char)10000;
output += testNumber;
File.WriteAllText(destFilePath, output, Encoding.UTF8);
```

**Result:**

```
✐
```

Comment: You can concatentate a char to a string using `+=` so you can simplify the second line to `output += testNumber;`

Answer (score 0):

you should use BinaryReader and BinaryWriter to read and write your data as byte.
use this code:

```
        using(BinaryWriter binaryWriter = new BinaryWriter(File.OpenWrite("YOUR_PATH")))
        {
              binaryWriter.Write(10000);
        }
```

and to read use these commands:

```
        using (BinaryReader binaryReader = new BinaryReader(File.OpenRead("YOUR_PATH")))
        {
            int i = binaryReader.ReadInt32();
        }
```